# React native background actions intent app

Tags: react-native, notifications

I am using react native background actions but as i am getting a notification when i click on the notification. I is opening gallery in the app by default. I want to open my app. Not able to get how can i open app on click on the notification.

```
const options = {
    taskName: 'Downloading',
    taskTitle: 'ExampleTask title',
    taskDesc: 'ExampleTask description',
    taskIcon: {
      name: 'ic_launcher',
      type: 'mipmap',
    },
    color: '#ff00ff',
    linkingURI: 'yourSchemeHere://chat/jane', // See Deep Linking for more info
    parameters: {
      delay: 15000,
    },
  };
```

Not getting how to use linking to open my app instead of the gallery using intent filter or something else.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the respective app when the user clicks on the notification of react native background action service.

Take these two steps -

1. Add intent filter on AndroidManifest.xml located at android/app/src/main. Under application activity tag.

> Also, verify this line "android:launchMode="singleTask"" should be
> there in activity tag. if not then please add it
>
> ```
> <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native"> 
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>     <data android:scheme="technomizeEMS" /> // Your custom scheme name then in second step we'll add this on linkingURI
> </intent-filter>
> ```

2. Add linkingUri in the configuration option of the start method. (The important takeaway for linkingURI is to add the same name as added on intent-filter
   in data tag android:scheme in AndroidManifest.xml and also append :// )

> ```
> const options = {
>           taskName: 'Task Name',
>           taskTitle: 'Task Title',
>           taskDesc: 'Task Description',
>           taskIcon: {
>             name: 'ic_launcher',
>             type: 'mipmap',
>           },
>           color: '#ff00ff',
>           // The important take away for linkingURI is to add same name as added on intent-filter
>           // in data tag android:scheme in AndroidManifest.xml and also append ://
>           linkingURI: 'technomizeEMS://', // See Deep Linking for more info
>           parameters: {
>             delay: 1000,
>           },
> };
> await BackgroundService.start(this.veryIntensiveTask, options);
> ```

For more detail you can refer here

https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions#deep-linking

Hope it will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)